# API connect published api in developer portal can't work

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/apiconnect/apic_tutorial.html#apic_tutorial_01

- Follow previous link to do create loopback project named ibmsvt and do test locally, we can post and get.
- then publish this api as running api app on bluemix and we will get api target url and tls file.
- type url and tls in api designer invoke, and publish api product again.
- check api connect service and we can find that published api product has been published, configure developer portal, and invite developers
- login developer portal and register one app
- subscribe app to api product and run post command.

We will see that we only get can't post error information...

Please see attachment info for error info and api file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the screen capture provided, it looks like you're displaying the logs for the loopback application deployed on bluemix.  It also looks like the POST request from APIConnect hit the Bluemix application as well.  However, I'm unable to see the exact message of the error.  What error did you get when you execute the POST from APIConnect?  I suspect the POST did not include the $(request.path), what did you change the invoke url to be ?  Can provide the x-ibm-configuration section in your yaml file?  It will be located in your /definitions.

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: The problem was exactly this - user did not include $(request.path) in the URL

Answer (score 0):

I am just have the exact problem, and struggled for days on redoing the tutorial several times, but still met with the same problem until found the upper reply, and gave me a hint.

In the tutorial, it says like the following:

> Update the following fields with the values you copied previously: 
>   Invoke URL: Insert the API target URL. You must specify the secure protocol HTTPS. For example:
>
> `apiconnect-ca3283b0-525c-488d-993b-3ab72fca78d0.youremail-dev.apic.mybluemix.net`
>
> TLS Profile: Insert the API invoke tls-profile. 
>   For example:
>
> `client:Loopback-client`

The origininal URL is `$(runtime-url)$(request.path)$(request.search)`.

And the correct URL after updating is like following:

**https://apiconnect-ca3283b0-525c-488d-993b-3ab72fca78d0.youremail-dev.apic.mybluemix.net$(request.path)**

no slash before $(request.path), and $(request.search) should be deleted.

I also checked a tutorial video, it also do like this, but the screen for this step is passed away very quickly, you will not pay attention to this detail normally.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qku71JLv8vA&list=PLFa8jnU0KqE2eW5E449ziaurv8obSbcou&index=3&cm_mc_uid=24774488665514672571374&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1468400063